# Equivalent Data Types in Java

Tags: java, android, database, bigdata, type-conversion

I am developing an Android application and it is dealing with BigML big data server.  I need to parse the data in the following formats.

```
int16
int8
```

What are the equivalent data types in Java/Android for the above mentioned types?

Comment: short and byte, both signed ?

Comment: @blackbelt: They only contain positive values, with 0. So, it is 'unsigned' right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are *no unsigned data types in Java*.

So if you are looking for signed types then `int8 -> byte` and `int16 -> short`

> They only contain positive values, with 0. So, it is 'unsigned' right?

Yes then they are unsigned, but as I already told you Java does not support unsigned types. So what you can do is use `int8 -> short` and `int16 -> int`

Comment: I have provided the answer to your question on unsigned.

Answer (score 3):

[Java Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

> byte: The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive). The byte data type can be useful for saving memory in large arrays, where the memory savings actually matters. They can also be used in place of int where their limits help to clarify your code; the fact that a variable's range is limited can serve as a form of documentation.
>
> short: The short data type is a 16-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -32,768 and a maximum value of 32,767 (inclusive). As with byte, the same guidelines apply: you can use a short to save memory in large arrays, in situations where the memory savings actually matters.

Comment: "the fact that a variable's range is limited can serve as a form of documentation." - This has got to be the best thing I've read today.

Answer (score 2):

In Java an int8 would be a byte, and you can use short for int16.

Comment: Narendra is right, I blatantly lied prior to editing the comment :)